# finding the most amount of times a substring appears successively in a string

Tags: python, string, search, substring

I have a long string of characters and not only am I trying to find if a substring of those characters exists within the larger string, I'm also trying to find the longest run of successive instances.

For example... in the code snippet below I've found that I can use "count" to see how many times the substring b appears in a.  That result is 5.  However, what I'm trying to identify is the longest successive run, which would be 3 (where 'abc' appears back to back to back in the middle).  I'm having difficulty running through the logic of this one.  Any advice would be appreciated.

```
a = "abcxyzabcabcabcxyzabcxyz"

b = "abc"

total = a.count(b)

print(total)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fairly simple with a while loop:

```
def func(a, b): 
    n = 1 
    while b*n in a: 
        n += 1 
    return n - 1
```

Comment: Probably perfectly fast for any reasonable string, but quite inefficient algorithmically. +1

Comment: It is possible that if the string is really long, this solution would run out of memory or run very slowly due to the number of repeated searches performed though

Comment: If this runs out of memory then you've already used up half your memory with the string `a`.  **Downvoter:** substring checks are highly optimized in Python, so in practice I'd be surprised to see a faster version than this, despite the algorithmic inefficiency (but happy to be proved wrong).

Answer (score 0):

One possible and naive solution is to use the python `index` function to identify the closest index of the substring. From there you can simply continue searching ahead for the substring until you find a point where it doesnt appear anymore, then call `index` again to skip ahead.

Example:

```
a = "abcxyzabcabcabcxyzabcxyz"
b = "abc"

curr_index = a.index(b)
longest_count = 0
current_count = 0

while curr_index < len(a):
    if a[curr_index : curr_index + len(b)] == b:
        curr_index += len(b)
        current_count += 1
    else:
        if longest_count < current_count:
            longest_count = current_count
        try:
            curr_index = a.index(b, curr_index)
        except ValueError:
            # Substring no longer found in string slice
            break
        current_count = 0

if longest_count < current_count:
    longest_count = current_count

print(longest_count)
```

This just returns the longest repeating count, but it doesn't return the location where it starts. Adding that functionality, however, is trivial.

Comment: You can keep using index for your search

Answer (score 0):

Keep calling `a.index` on `b` with the appropriate indices. If the index is the start of your subset, you're in the same run. Otherwise, start a new run:

```
def longest_run(string, pattern):
    longest = 0
    current = 0
    start = 0
    while True:
        try:
            ind = string.index(pattern, start)
            if ind == start:
                current += 1
            else:
                if current > longest:
                    longest = current
                current = 1
            start += len(pattern)
        except ValueError:
            return longest
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall` with a pattern that matches one or more times of `b` (use `re.escape` to prevent `b` from being interpreted as regex), then map the returning strings to `len` and pass them to `max` to obtain the length of the longest match, and then divide that length by the length of `b` to get the number of times `b` is repeated:

```
import re
max(map(len, re.findall('(?:%s)+' % re.escape(b), a))) // len(b)
```